# Custom summary when share facebook

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, yii

I want to insert new break and add link into summary when i share via facebook like this:

[image]

Line: "Red RC" is a link... I tried but not work... I don't know that Facebook have support it.
Anyone know???
Can anybody give me link to any document about it...? Thanks...

Comment: You want to add a break before or after the link?

Comment: I want add before Source: Red RC

Comment: show what you tried. i think it is caption not summary

Comment: how is this question related to yii?

Answer (score 0):

in the url link set meta tag in head

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />   
<meta property="og:image" content="imageurl" />   
<meta property="og:description" content="url" />
```

There some other meta tag you can check
http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags